# Why does the QueryTable WebTable number differs when I run this code on different PCs?

Tags: excel, vba

I run this code each morning to update stats from FanGraphs. Up until about 1 month ago, this code worked the same on my home PC and my work PC. But now the ".WebTables =" line works differently between the two PCs. This code is used in several other places in my workbook for different URLs and tables. It is the same issue for this ".WebTables =" line of code.

On my home PC, I use `.WebTables = "21"`. Data gets imported into columns A:S with column B being blank (I don't know why, that's just how it is imported). On my work PC, this line needs to be `.WebTables = "12"`.
With the `.WebTables = "12"` version, the columns that are imported are A:R with column B not being blank. This difference messes with my calculations on the sheet.

Why is there a difference on how this gets imported between my two PCs? Last I checked, both are using VBA version 7.1 and the same references. Unless there are other specs on my PCs I need to check or references I need to check or update in VBA?

```
Sub RP_stats()

    Sheet46.Select
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "URL;https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=rel&lg=all&qual=1&type=c,11,114,13,120,121,217,113,43,44,48,51,42,6,122,223&season=2019&month=0&season1=2019&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&sort=8,d&page=1_400"
    'url = custom leader board for season long RP pitching stats

    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Range("a:s").ClearContents
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Sheet46.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        URL, Destination:=Range("a2"))
        '.Name = "RPstats"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebTables = "21"           'the table number to get the right table of data. THIS TABLE DIFFERS BETWEEN PCs FOR SOME REASON
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to using xmlhttp and then use the id of the table to target it

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, hTable As HTMLTable  '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=rel&lg=all&qual=1&type=c,11,114,13,120,121,217,113,43,44,48,51,42,6,122,223&season=2019&month=0&season1=2019&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&sort=8,d&page=1_400", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Set hTable = html.querySelector("#LeaderBoard1_dg1_ctl00")
    Writetable hTable, 1, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Sub

Public Sub Writetable(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)

    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim tSection As Object, tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long, tBody As Object
    r = startRow
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim headers As Object, header As Object, columnCounter As Long
        Set headers = hTable.getElementsByTagName("th")
        For Each header In headers
            If header.className = "rgHeader" Or header.className = "rgHeader rgSorted" Then
                columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
                .Cells(startRow, columnCounter) = header.innerText
            End If
        Next header
        startRow = startRow + 1
        Set tBody = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
        For Each tSection In tBody               'HTMLTableSection
            Set tRow = tSection.getElementsByTagName("tr") 'HTMLTableRow
            For Each tr In tRow
                If Not (IsError(Application.Match(tr.className, Array("rgRow", "rgAltRow"), 0))) Then
                    r = r + 1
                    Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                    c = 1
                    For Each td In tCell         'DispHTMLElementCollection
                        .Cells(r, c).Value = td.innerText 'HTMLTableCell
                        c = c + 1
                    Next td
                End If
            Next tr
        Next tSection
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try this?